# Display image 1 if checkbox is checked, image 2 if is unchecked

Tags: php, if-statement, checkbox

**this is my html:**

```
<input class="no-check-border-win" type="checkbox" name="Elevator" value="y"     
[elevator]/>Elevator<br />
```

**where [elevator] is:**

```
if ($_POST['Elevator']=='y') echo 'checked="checked"';
```

**i found this but doesn t work!!!**

```
if(isset($_POST['Elevator']) &&
$_POST['Elevator'] == 'Yes')
{
echo '<img src="http://mysite/image1.png" border=0>';
}
else
{
echo '<img src="http://mysite/image2.png" border=0>'}
```

**actually i have this and works fine:**

```
$Elevator = $_POST[Elevator]?'y':'n'; 
echo 'Elevator: '.$row[Elevator].'<br />';
```

**Instead of 'y' or 'n' I would like to display 'image 1' or 'image 2'...*Thx..***

Comment: You need to explain what you're trying to do / what you want people to help you with...

Answer (score 0):

You have two (or more) problems with your code:

- You have not put the check box in a form
- You have not checked if `elevator` was set properly...

To solve this, you should do something like this:

form.php

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <form name="f1" method="POST" action="process.php">
 <input class="no-check-border-win" type="checkbox" name="Elevator" value="y"     />Elevator<br/> 
 <input type="submit"/>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

process.php

```
if((isset($_POST['Elevator'])) && ($_POST['Elevator'] == 'y'))
{
echo '<img src="http://mysite/image1.png" border=0>';
}
else
{
echo '<img src="http://mysite/image2.png" border=0>'
}
```

If that does not work then try echoing the contents of `$_POST['Elevator']` on the `process.php` page and then show me the result. Let me know if you need further help!

Comment: @Olasz Any time! Please consider accepting my answer by pressing the checkmark beside my answer :)